# How to install drivers/recommended updates via windows update in windows 10?

Tags: windows-update, drivers, windows-10

My virus scanner (ESET Endpoint Security) tells me that Windows has recommended updates for me. But if I try to search for them via Windows Update, it tells me that everything is up to date. (Installation mode is "automatic" and "Updates for other Microsoft products" is checked. Device installation settings are set to "Yes (recommended)") . [image: ESET Endpoint Security]

With [Boxstarter](http://boxstarter.org/) I can do updates via the command line, but if I try to install them I get the message `Requires user input and will not be downloaded`:

```
PS C:\> Install-WindowsUpdate -criteria "IsInstalled=0 and Type='Driver'" -acceptEula
+ Boxstarter starting Checking for updates...
Starting windows update service
+ Boxstarter finished Checking for updates... 00:00:26.7356293
8 Updates found
 * Intel - Other hardware - Intel(R) Watchdog Timer Driver (Intel(R) WDT) Requires user input and will not be downloaded
 * INTEL driver update for Intel(R) Xeon(R) E3 - 1200/1500 v5/6th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) PCIe Controller (x16) - 1901 Requires user input and will not be downloaded
 * INTEL driver update for Intel(R) 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller - A145 Requires user input and will not be downloaded
 * INTEL driver update for Intel(R) 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Root Port #17 - A167 Requires user input and will not be downloaded
 * INTEL driver update for Intel(R) Xeon(R) E3 - 1200/1500 v5/6th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) Host Bridge/DRAM Registers - 191F Requires user input and will not be downloaded
 * INTEL driver update for Intel(R) 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 - A110 Requires user input and will not be downloaded
 * INTEL driver update for Intel(R) 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9 - A118 Requires user input and will not be downloaded
 * American Megatrends Inc. - Other hardware - LENOVO H110 System Firmware 0.30 Requires user input and will not be downloaded
Stopping win update service and setting its startup type to Manual
PS C:\>
```

What are these updates for? How can I install them?

Best regards!
    Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with ESET (which is a fantastic product) on Windows 10.  Maybe not quite a bug, but somewhat confusing.  The "updates" in your list above all appear to be not-so-important driver updates.  My recommendation is to go into ESET and change the settings such that you're only notified by ESET if there're critical updates that you're missing, which there shouldn't be, since you have Windows Update configured to do its thing automatically.

To open the ESET console, click the notification area icons, click the arrow to show hidden icons if necessary, then click the ESET logo.  Or search for ESET Nod32 Smart Security or ESET Nod32 Endpoint Antivirus or whatever exact product you have running.

1. Open ESET, press F5 for advanced view.
2. Tools -> [expand] Microsoft Windows Update
3. Change notification level to something like Critical or Important.  (A German to English translator leads me to believe you currently have the "recommended" level selected.

**But to really answer your last question, here's how to install the newest drivers if you want to:**

1. Device Manager
2. View -> Show hidden devices
3. Find the hardware which you want to update the driver(s) for.  Right click it in the list, Update Driver Software
4. Choose Search Automatically

--You also might be able to drill a bit deeper into the Windows Update settings to try to make these drivers install automatically.  I'm not sure if Windows is trying to install them and they're failing, or if Windows is just skipping them due to low importance.

Comment: Thanks for the input - so the manual update via the Device Manager is the "Required user input", that is mentioned by "Boxstarter"? And second question: Are there other "more important" driver updates that are installed automatically?